# jquery .find when using array element

Tags: jquery

Here is a code sample:

```
$('#TBI tr.k-state-selected')[0].cells[0].find("input").val(selectedId).change();
```

I'm actually trying the change the value of a cell on a KendoUI grid.  But for some reason it's giving me an "Object does not support this method" on the .find.

If I do this:

```
$('#TBI tr.k-state-selected').find("input").val(selectedId).change();
```

It doesn't give me the error (but not the results I want either).  When I take the array elements away, it seems fine from a syntax perspective.

So my question becomes: How do I do a find such as this when there are array elements involved.

Comment: Is `.cells[0]` a jQuery object? If not, try: `$($('#TBI tr.k-state-selected')[0].cells[0]).find("input").val(selectedId).change();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow your pseudo code logic, you might want

```
$('#TBI tr.k-state-selected:eq(0) td:eq(0) input').val(selectedId).change();
```

that is :

the inputs in the first cell of the first row with class k-state-selected in the element of id TBI.

Comment: For the OP's benefit: also learn about `:first` and `:nth-child`. Those two plus `:eq` will help a lot if you're doing anything remotely complex with dom manipulation

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `cell[0]` is a jQuery object so you wouldn't be able to call a jQuery method on it.

Try wrapping it into a jQuery object again

```
var $cell = $($('#TBI tr.k-state-selected')[0].cells[0]);

$cell.find("input").val(selectedId).change();
```

Or off course, fixing up your selector to return the desired element to begin with as in `dystroy`'s answer would save the hassle of wrapping it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**eq**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) jquery function to get jquery object instead of getting javascript object by using `[0]`

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/uqalif/3/edit)**

```
$('#TBI tr.k-state-selected').eq(0).find("td:eq(0) input").val(selectedId).change();
```